# How do I open a file from Java? (it is a .bat file to be specific)

Tags: java, eclipse, file

This is what i tried:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;

public class File {
    static java.io.File myFile = new java.io.File("C:/Users/me/Desktop/file.bat");
    public void hello(){
        Desktop.open(myFile);
    }
}
```

I keep on getting the error:

> Cant make a static reference to a non static method.

Comment: The method `open()` is not static. You need to call it on an instance of `Desktop`. Also, depending on the application associated with `.bat` files, you might not be running the file, only opening it in a text editor for example.

Answer (score 4):

Do the following

```
public void hello() {
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        desktop.open(myFile);
    }
}
```

Since the method `open()` is not static, you cannot call it statically on `Desktop` like `Desktop.open()`. You must call it on an instance, which you can get with `Desktop.getDesktop()` which is static.

The [`open(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) method itself will launch the application associated with the file extension, it might not be running the file like you would expect with a `.bat`.